# JMockit verify injectable method called twice with different arguments

Tags: java, jmockit

I would like to verify that an injected dependency method is called twice with different argument types. So suppose my class is:

```
public class MyClass {
    @PersistenceContext(name = "PU")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void doSomething() {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        Address customerAddress = new Address;
        entityManager.persist(customer)
        entityManager.persist(customerAddress);
    }
}
```

@PersistenceContext is a Java EE specific annotation to tell an application server to inject an EntityManager for a specific peristence unit.

So I would like to test that persist is called twice, once being passed a Customer object and another time being passed an Address object.

Creating the following test class passes:

```
public class MyClassTests {
    @Tested
    MyClass myClass;
    @Injectable
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void TestPersistCustomerAndAddress() {
        new Expectations() {{
            entityManager.persist(withAny(Customer.class));
            entityManager.persist(withAny(Address.class));
        }};

        myClass.doSomething();
    }
}
```

However JMockit seems to be ignoring the class type passed to withAny. I can basically change withAny to withAny(Date.class) and the test will still pass.

Is there a way to verify specific object types being passed to persist?

Comment: Note there is no `withAny(Class)` method, but only a `withAny(T)` method, where `T` is a generic type parameter which merely avoids the need for a type cast. I would also recommend setting up your Java IDE so you can promptly see API documentation from the code editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using withInstanceOf(Customer.class)? I think that should do what you want.